# Numpy sorting for a matrix with return_counts=True

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 3d numpy array that shows the values of poker cards. Each row has 5 cards. And there are 10 players. I now want to create a ranking of how many times each card occurs for each player and sort them. This needs to be done separately for each row. The third dimension can ve ignored (hence a 0) as it contains the suits and is not relevant for this part of the problem.

```
cards[:,:,0]
Out[317]: 
array([[  6.,   4.,   9.,  12.,  12.],
       [  8.,   4.,  12.,   7.,   9.],
       [ 10.,   2.,   3.,   7.,   3.],
       [ 12.,   6.,   7.,   4.,  12.],
       [  5.,   8.,   4.,  12.,   3.],
       [  3.,   1.,   9.,   7.,  10.],
       [ 11.,   9.,   4.,   9.,  11.],
       [  3.,   6.,   7.,   9.,  11.],
       [ 12.,   6.,   5.,  10.,   1.],
       [  5.,   4.,   1.,  11.,  12.]])
```

The following does the job for the first row:

```
np.unique(np.sort(cards[0,:,0]), return_counts=True)
 (array([  4.,   6.,   9.,  12.]), array([1, 1, 1, 2]))
```

How can I do it for all rows as a numpy matrix operation without a loop. It has be be in numpy only (no collections or lists etc).

The following does't work as the array is somehow flattened. How can I avoid this?

```
np.unique(np.sort(cards[:,:,0]), return_counts=True)
(array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
         12.]), array([3, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8]))
```

Comment: Since there might be different number of unique cards per row, you can't have a regular 2D array as output I would think. So, what must be the output format?

Comment: Yes you are right. Is there a possibility to fill the blanks with nan? It's important to do this a matrix operation as there will be several million rows and only numpy is fast enough.

Comment: So, fill the blanks for both the unique elements and their counts with `NaNs`?

Comment: Yes that's fine. Or a 0 is ok as well.

Comment: It seems that what I wanted to is not possible. I have though of a manual way to do it so that the amount of columns will be equal in each row, so I rephrased the question as follows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602484/numpy-broadcasting