# Numpy broadcasting

Tags: numpy

The following code gives me how many times the elements in a (0-11) occur in the first row of array c. (a==c[0]). How can I adjust this code so it also does the same for all rows in c, not just c[0]. Essentially a for loop.

```
import numpy as np
c=(np.random.rand(2,5)*12).round()
print (c)

a=np.arange(12).reshape(12,1)
print (np.sum(a==c[0],axis=1))
```

The result should look like this, but without the for loop:

```
for n in range(2):
    a=np.arange(12).reshape(12,1)
    print (np.sum(a==c[n],axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) that would incur heavy memory usage, you could do -

```
(c[...,None] == np.arange(12)).sum(1)
```

For bigger sized `c`, a better way would be to not disturb `c` and just move around `np.arange(12)`, like so -

```
(c == (np.arange(12)[:,None,None])).sum(-1).T
```

Here's some proof on that *theory* -

```
In [28]: c=(np.random.rand(2000,5000)*12).round()

In [29]: %timeit (c[...,None] == np.arange(12)).sum(1)
1 loops, best of 3: 423 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit (c == (np.arange(12)[:,None,None])).sum(-1).T
1 loops, best of 3: 232 ms per loop
```

Comment: wow amazing! What's the ... standing for? I can't find anything in the doc

Comment: @nickpick I call it - Throw everything to the front. So, basically pushes all dims to the front and thus is essentially same as `c[:,:,None]` for this case.